# Examples of free objects (beginner question)

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I am trying to understand what are the free objects in the category of topological spaces. 
The definition on Wikipedia is clear to me, that is:

Given a concrete category **C** and a functor **F** such that **F:** **C** $\rightarrow$ **Set** faithful, $X$ is a set called basis and $A\in$ **C** an object, $i: X \rightarrow F(A)$ the canonical injection. $A$ is called a free object on $X$ with respect to $i$ if they satisfy the universal property: for any object $B$ and any map between sets $f:X \rightarrow F(B)$ there exists a unique morphism $g: A\rightarrow B$ such that $f=F(g) \circ i$.

Can anybody help me with this question? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The free objects in $\mathbf{Top}$ are the discrete spaces.

It’s easy to see that discrete spaces are free objects: if $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a discrete space, $\langle Y,\tau'\rangle$ is any space, and $f:X\to Y$ is any set function, $f$ is a continuous map from $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ to $\langle Y,\tau'\rangle$.

If $\tau$ is not the discrete topology, let $Y=X$ and take $\tau'$ to be the discrete topology on $Y$; then the identity function from $X$ to $Y$ is not continuous as a map from $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ to $\langle Y,\tau'\rangle$.